# Brighten the screen on my HDMI connected TV

Tags: linux-mint

How do I brighten the screen on my HDMI connected TV while streaming movies via a Dell desktop with Mint OS. The picture is just too dark.  Is there a Command that I can use?

Comment: adjust the TV brightness control

Comment: Tried that. Not bright enough. The signal from the computer is connected to a regular monitor via USB and the picture is beautiful. The TV is connected to the computer via USB and hdmi to the TV. TV picture is very dark and cannot compensate with the TV brightness controls. I assumed linux would have a command that would allow a brightness adjustment.

Comment: `TV is connected to the computer via USB and hdmi` ... there is no mention of a USB connection in your question ... what is the purpose of the USB connection?